# Как преобразовать строку в массив обьектов? JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как я могу преобразовать строку в массив объектов?
Есть строка

```
{ _id: 57fa6bd8cc9b4a17d085f53a, title: 'max', private: true },
{ _id: 57fa6e10b8455715f48e793b, title: 'room1', private: false },
{ _id: 57fa6e25b8455715f48e793c, title: 'room2', private: false }
```

Команда

```
var test = JSON.parse(str);
```

Возвращает ошибку

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token _.

Если до `JSON.parse` выполнить `JSON.stringify()`, то ошибки нет, но возвращается точно такая же строка.

**Update**

Получаю список комнат из БД и отправляю на рендер.

```
if (req.user){
        mongoose.model('Room')
            .find()
            .select('title private')
            .exec(function(err,rooms){
                roomsObj = rooms;
                res.render('chat.ejs', {
                    isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
                    user: req.user ? req.user : null,
                    rooms: roomsObj
                });
            });
    } else res.json("You should log in!");
```

К сожалению, не разобрался как передать данные с помощью сокетов от файла route.js до server.js. Решил попробовать передать на клиент и от клиента уже на server.js. Поскольку объект в таком виде (<%= roomsObj %>) на передается, пришлось засунуть его в строку.
Код с клиента

`socket.emit('send_rooms', rommsObj = '<%= roomsObj %>');`

Comment: У Вас неправильные `_id`, т..е. без ', что указывает на число в этом поле, а тут присутствуют и цифры и буквы, что является невалидным json. Если в `_id` будут присутствовать только цифры, то все ок.

Comment: вообще ваш json похож на ответ от mongodb, а привидите код который формирует эту строку?

Comment: @Naumov Это и есть ответ от монго)  Обновил вопрос.

Comment: я так понимаю у вас nodejs? вам надо этот объект закодировать в json а потом уже вывести или он уже в json приходит как он выглядит перед отправкой на страницу?

Comment: @Naumov Из базы я достаю и отправляю объект, на клиент приходит тоже объект, но в строчке socket.emit('send_rooms', rommsObj = '<%= roomsObj %>'); (Отправляет данные уже в нужный мне файл) нельзя отправить объект, и приходится помещать его в строку, то есть в кавычки ' '

Comment: `socket.emit('send_rooms', rommsObj = '<%= JSON.stringify(roomsObj) %>');` попробуйте так

Comment: @Naumov опять ошибка( Unexpected token _

Comment: Покажите какой json получился такой же или другой?

Comment: Заменились кавычки на "&#39;"    { _id: 57fa6bd8cc9b4a17d085f53a, title: &#39;max&#39;, private: true },{ _id: 57fa6e10b8455715f48e793b, title: &#39;room1&#39;, private: false },{ _id: 57fa6e25b8455715f48e793c, title: &#39;room2&#39;, private: false }

Comment: а можете сдампить roomsObj до отправки в шабол и с использованием stringify,

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, на клиенте:    var Dump = <%= JSON.stringify(roomsObj)%>;    Но в браузере ошибка (Unexpected token &) в строке `var Dump = [{&#34;_id&#34;:&#34;57fa6bd8cc9b4a17d085f53a&#34;` ...

Comment: @MaximCherevatov давай в чат

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46588/discussion-between-naumov-and-maxim-cherevatov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

собственно в чате нашли решение, необходимо конвертировать объект в json и вывести без перевода в html сущность

```
socket.emit('send_rooms', rommsObj = <%- JSON.stringify(roomsObj) %>);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Формат JSON](http://www.json.org/json-ru.html) является достаточно строгим.

В нем жестко указано, что ключи - это строки, а строки должны быть в двойных кавычках.

Кроме того, в json нет типа guid, поэтому значения полей id, должны быть в виде строк, то есть так же обрамлены в двойные кавычки, то же самой и со значениями поля `title`

```js
console.log(
  JSON.parse(`[{ "_id": "57fa6bd8cc9b4a17d085f53a", "title": "max", "private": true },
{ "_id": "57fa6e10b8455715f48e793b", "title": "room1", "private": false },
{ "_id": "57fa6e25b8455715f48e793c", "title": "room2", "private": false }]`)
);
```

Comment: Вам не кажеться что ваш ответ поспешен, так как человек не руками формирует json а где то в backend

Comment: @Naumov, нет, не кажется. Ответ о конкретной причине ошибки. Не важно почему получилась именно такая строка, важно, почему они неверна.